# ArrayMap with ArrayAdapter in Gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-arrayadapter

I would like to display the key/value pairs of an ArrayMap with an ArrayAdapter in a GridView with two columns.

```
ArrayMap<String, String> testmap = new ArrayMap<String, String>();
    testmap.put("one", "eins");
    testmap.put("two", "drei");
    testmap.put("three", "vier");
    testmap.put("four", "fünf");
    testmap.put("five", "sechs");

    ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testmap);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    gridView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

This is the error message:

```
Error:(49, 45) error: no suitable constructor found for  
ArrayAdapter(NumbersActivity,int,ArrayMap<String,String>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not          applicable
(argument mismatch; ArrayMap<String,String> cannot be converted to int)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not    applicable
(argument mismatch; ArrayMap<String,String> cannot be converted to  String[])
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; ArrayMap<String,String> cannot be converted to    List<String>)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you read your error message?

Comment: Yes, I did and I'm not skilled enough to work it out. That's why I ask. I need another constructor... But which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a list of map to use `ArrayAdapter`

```
ArrayList<ArrayMap<String, String>> testmap = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayMap<String, String> map = new ArrayMap<>();
    map.put("one", "eins");
    map.put("two", "drei");
    map.put("three", "vier");
    map.put("four", "fünf");
    map.put("five", "sechs");

    testmap.add(map);

    ArrayAdapter<ArrayMap<String, String>> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, testmap);
    gridView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

And in order to preserve the insertion of values in your map, use [`LinkedHashMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

**EDIT**

To display values in different cell, create a new map every time you put values in it

```
ArrayMap<String, String> map = new ArrayMap<>();
    map.put("one", "eins");
    testmap.add(map);
    map = new ArrayMap<>();
    map.put("two", "drei");
    testmap.add(map);
    map = new ArrayMap<>();
    map.put("three", "vier");
    testmap.add(map);
    map = new ArrayMap<>();
    map.put("four", "fünf");
    testmap.add(map);
    map = new ArrayMap<>();
    map.put("five", "sechs");
    testmap.add(map);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The ArrayAdapter takes only one argument.

Comment: You solved the issue related to the error message. Now the five key/value pairs are displayed in one cell of the GridView: {one=eins, two=drei, ...}

Comment: I have added code if you want to display in different cell

Comment: Thank you for your help!